# Setting maximum memory when using Distributed Memory Cache in .NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am writing a .NET Core based WebAPI. I want to utilize a Distributed Memory Cache for my development environment by registering an IDistributedCache in Startup.ConfigureServices.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (_hostContext.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
        {
          options.Configuration = "localhost";
          options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
        });
    }
}
```

However, I dont want the data caching to eat up most of my RAM. How can I limit the DistributedMemoryCache to use only 2GIG for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AddDistributedMemoryCache()` has an overload that allows you to configure a `MemoryDistributedCacheOptions`. You can do:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(options =>
{
   options.SizeLimit = 2000 * 1024 * 1024; // 2000MB
});
```

It looks like the default is [200MB](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryDistributedCacheOptions.cs#L12).